# How can i run the window of the started program minimized

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i want to run a .wav-file. This is with

`start "" SoundFile.wav`

totally practical. But how can i run the window of the standard-windows-soundplayer minimized? So that nothing of my view changes?

`start "" SoundFile.wav /MIN`

`start "" SoundFile.wav /min`

`start "" SoundFile.wav -MIN`

`start "" SoundFile.wav -min`

didn't work sadly.
Can you help me?
Greets.

Comment: Run `start /?` and look at where `/MIN` is mentioned in relation to `[command/program]` and `[parameters]`

Comment: have you tried moving `/MIN` to be part of the start paramater? i.e `start /MIN "" "somecmd"`

Comment: @TripeHound - it is mentioned after the path.

Comment: @Gerhard, yes, i did and the outcome is the same: Groove-Player (I didn't change the default program) still opens fully and not minimized.

Comment: @JuliusCicero It's after `[/D path]`, which is the directory to launch the in, but before the thing to be launched. However, if `start "" /min soundfile.wav` doesn't work, then either your sound player is switching its display mode after it was started, or it's possibly because your launching the sound file rather than the player itself. You _might_ try `start "" /min wmplayer soundfile.wav` and see if that helps.

Comment: @TripeHound Yes, this ```start "" /min wmplayer soundfile.wav``` did it. Thank you so much. Greets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but i am not familiar with stackoverflow, so i can't make it *that* understandable, but i hope that this is enough.

In a simple way, you could just use a VBS like this:

```
s = createobject("WScript.Shell")
s.run "music.mp3", 2
```

Or create an automatic and CLI program to do this:

**runmusic.bat**

```
@echo off
set music=%1
set music=%music:"=%
if ":" neq "%music:~1,1%" set music=%cd%\%music%
if "%music:~-4%" neq ".mp3" set music=%music%.mp3
set katorn=%random%
echo >>"%temp%\%katorn%.vbs" set s = createobject("WScript.Shell")
echo >>"%temp%\%katorn%.vbs" s.run "%music%", 2
cscript "%temp%\%katorn%.vbs"
:: Uncomment the next line to autodelete the vbs file.
:: del /q /f "%temp%\%katorn%.vbs"
```

Usage:

```
runmusic (name or full path with quotation marks)
```

In a "professional way" you could do a shortcut file that starts the file minimized.
It could be useful if you needs the musics to have the "artist logo" or something like that, also if you don't want to use an CMD all the time...

Delete all comments to execute.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell")
strDesktop = "X:\Shortcutlocation\yoo"
Set Shortcut = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop + "\MusicNameMaybe.lnk")
Shortcut.WindowStyle = "7" 
Shortcut.IconLocation = "X:\IconPath\youricon.ico" // You can delete this and the file will be the same ever and forever. 
Shortcut.TargetPath = "X:\yourpath\music.mp3"
Shortcut.Save
```

And you don't have to keep the shortcuts on the desktop if you don't want to, you don't even have to keep them fixed. Example:

**runmusic.bat**

```
@echo off
set music=%1
set music=%music:"=%
if ":" neq "%music:~1,1%" set music=%cd%\%music%
set music=%music%.mp3
set katorn=%random%
echo >>"%temp%\%katorn%.vbs" Set WshShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell")
echo >>"%temp%\%katorn%.vbs" strDesktop = "%temp%"
echo >>"%temp%\%katorn%.vbs" Set Shortcut = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop + "\%katorn%.lnk")
echo >>"%temp%\%katorn%.vbs" Shortcut.WindowStyle = "7" 
echo >>"%temp%\%katorn%.vbs" Shortcut.TargetPath = "%music%"
echo >>"%temp%\%katorn%.vbs" Shortcut.Save
cscript "%temp%\%katorn%.vbs"
:: Uncomment the next two lines to delete the temporary files.
:: del /q /f "%temp%\%katorn%.vbs"
:: del /q /f "%temp%\%katorn%.lnk"
echo Enjoy!
```

Usage:

```
runmusic (name or full path with quotation marks)
```

Now that you understand, you can even leave a folder with the songs and the other with just the customized shortcuts, which can come in handy.

***Hope this helps,

K.***

Comment: Yes indeed, thank you very much :) Greets

Comment: Can you set the answer as correct if it helped, please? Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I forgot.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Anything, just ask =)